# .net core object to Session without serialize

Tags: c#, session, serialization, asp.net-core-mvc

i use the   .net core  `"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session": "1.0.0"` to use the session in my .net core project and use the extension method witch is mention on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state) its like this

```
public static void Set<T>(this ISession session, string key, T value)
        {
            session.SetString(key, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));
        }
```

In my controller

```
HttpContext.Session.Set<BLL.clsPolicy>("PolicyDATAAPI", policyObj);
```

when i pass the object to session this doing the serialization 
it make the some problems in my object class like : private variables are not
serialize like that ,

any way to store object store in session without serialize ? ?

Answer (score 2):

Out of the box, in .Net Core, there is no way to store an object in session without serializing it.  If you want to add session support for an in memory object store you'd need to implement it.

To implement it you'd need to implement your own implementation of `ISession` and `ISessionStore` and register them with the DI container.  Then you'd need to add extension methods to `ISession` to support a `Set` method that takes a key and an object as parameters.  Internally in your implementation of ISession you could use a thread safe dictionary to store the objects.

But again, out of the box, .Net Core dos not provide support for storing non-serialized objects in memory.  If you want it, you'd have to write it.